# How does Aurora distribute Postgres function to read and write replica?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-aurora

How does Aurora distribute Postgres functions to read and write replica?

With Pgpool, I can make a list of `read_only_function_list` to tell it that it should redirect these functions to a read replica.
How do I do that with AWS Aurora?

Thank you.

Comment: You can use pgPool with Aurora, right?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I believe I can, but if it's possible to do with whatever built into Aurora, then that may be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aurora doesn't redirect q write query to a write replica or a read query to a read replica automatically.

Aurora will provide their users with a write endpoint and a read endpoint, then their users have to be context aware and pick the right endpoint on their own.

But in case of multiple read replicas, Aurora does provide a read distribute with DNS.